Double click to modify record
I'm trying to implement the double click function to open a new window and edit the information of a SQLite Database.
At the moment if I double click on a data of the table I get the error:
line 1968, in __call__     
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: edit_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

That's the command I would the programm execute after double click (I will update the new page after)
def edit_data():
        editor_data = Tk()
        editor_data.title("Scheda Cliente")
        editor_data.geometry("400x600")

And that is the code for double click:
self.customerlist.bind("<Double-Button-1>", edit_data)
        self.customerlist.pack()

I tried to find a guide to do that without success, so I'm stuck here

if 1 argument was given but your function takes 0 arguments have you tried making your function accept 1 argument so it matches the number of arguments passed?

The callback for event binding expects an argument, the Event object.

adding this code I solved and now opens a new windos but I get "parameters are of unsupported type" error
try: 
        with sqlite3.connect('dataDBG.db') as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute('SELECT customerid FROM dataDBG_clienti WHERE customerid=?', (id))
            row = cur.fetchone()
            
        if row:
            print('customerid')
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(e)


@RaffaeleAllocca It is another issue, so it is better to raise another question.
